# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error While sending a mail from java mail

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I am getting this error while sending out mail from my project.
Applications I was using are:

1. Eclipse IDE
2. Apache Tomcat

Here is the error

````
```Servlet.service() for servlet [controler.ForgotPassword] in context with path [/Banking_App] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.<init>(MailcapCommandMap.java:179)
    at javax.activation.CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(CommandMap.java:85)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getCommandMap(DataHandler.java:167)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:629)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:329)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:340)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1575)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2271)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2231)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
    at controler.ForgotPassword.service(ForgotPassword.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

Jul 17, 2020 7:28:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [controler.ForgotPassword] in context with path [/Banking_App] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/activation/registries/LogSupport
    at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.<init>(MailcapCommandMap.java:179)
    at javax.activation.CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(CommandMap.java:85)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getCommandMap(DataHandler.java:167)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:629)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:329)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:340)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1575)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2271)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2231)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
    at controler.ForgotPassword.service(ForgotPassword.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)```
````

Here is the java class from where it will send the mail:-

"ForgotPassword.java"

````
```@WebServlet("/ForgotPassword")
public class ForgotPassword extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ForgotPassword() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        HttpSession session1=request.getSession(true);
        session1.setAttribute("email",email);
        
        String fromEmail="abc@gmail.com";
        String psw="XYZ";
        
        String subject="DO NOT REPLY: Mail from Java Program";
        String msg="Hi, Click this link to reset your password "
                + "http://localhost:3030/Banking_App/resetPassWord.jsp";
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        
        Session session= Session.getDefaultInstance(prop
                , new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, psw);
        }
        }
        );
        try {       
            MimeMessage mesg=new MimeMessage(session);
            mesg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            mesg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            mesg.setSubject(subject);
            mesg.setText(msg);
            
            Transport.send(mesg);
            System.out.println("Mail Sent!!");
            
            response.sendRedirect("/Banking_App/forgotPassWordSuccessful.jsp");
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}```
````

I was trying to send a link through this mail for resetting the password, where I used two jar files and deploy them in project

1. javax.mail
2. javax.activation

[image: THIS IS Image of Error]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please check your tomcat version?

Comment: I am using the latest(9.0) one

Comment: what version of java and where you have deployed those jars?

Comment: I am using java 13.0.2 and I deployed those jar files on deployment assembly of project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this dependency and see if it works:

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0'
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also read [this article](https://nipafx.dev/java-11-migration-guide) for more info.